# SOAP - Create an element with zeep (python)

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I've to use a SOAP API for a project. 
For a specific method I've to send a complex type.

This complex type is declared like that:

```
<complexType name="specialList">
    <sequence>
        <element name=data" minOccurs="0"maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <complexType>
                <simpleContent>
                    <extension base="string">
                        <attribute name="key" type="string" use="required"/>
                    </extension>
                </simpleContent>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

This is an example:

```
<my_action type="specialList">
    <data key="myKey">MyValue</data>
    <data key="myOtherKey">MyOtherValue</data>
</my_action>
```

To access to the SOAP API, I use [zeep](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zeep/) (I tried with suds).
The first think I do is retrieve my "specialList".

```
special_list = client.get_type('ns1:specialList')
my_action = special_list(data=[data_1, data_2])
```

However I've a problem with the type "data". Indeed this type "data" is not declared. I cannot do a client.get_type("ns1:data").

I tried several time to create an simple element but without success.
Do you have an idea how to create this "special" data ?

In advance, thank you.

Sylvain

Answer (score 2):

can you try using AnyObject as indicated in their documentation: http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html

so in your code:

from zeep import xsd

```
special_list = client.get_type('ns1:specialList')
my_action = xsd.AnyObject(special_list, special_list(data=[data_1, data_2]))
```